# Asterisk TLS failing to work

Tags: asterisk, sip, tls1.2

I've followed the tutorial to a tee from the Wiki on TLS security, however, it is not working

**Configuration**

```
sip.conf

[general]
tlsenable=yes
tlsbinaddr=0.0.0.0
tlsclientmethod=tlsv1
tlscertfile=/etc/asterisk/secure-keys/asterisk.pem
register => tls://1234:password@<ip add for PBX>

[1234]
type=friend
transport=tls
context=Phones
host=dynamic
secret=password
```

**Creating the keys**

The commands I used to create Asterisk keys were:

```
./ast_tls_cert -C <ip of PBX>.mycompany.com -O "TEST" -d /etc/asterisk/secure-keys
```

The command I used to create the softphone key was:

```
./ast_tls_cert -m client -c /etc/asterisk/secure-keys/ca.crt -k /etc/asterisk/ca.key -C 1234.mycompany.com -O "test" -d /etc/asterisk/secure-keys -o 1234
```

I've copied over the 1234.pem and ca.crt file to the desktop containing the softphone, I have the softphone set to use TLS transport and I've selected the 1234.pem file as a TLS client certificate

**Problem**

It is telling me the Certificate common name did not match

It is also providing this "problem setting up ssl connection....SSL routines: ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca"

Answer (score 0):

I was opening the ca.crt file on the client as the .pem file, once I correctly installed the ca.crt file it made a peering with the server